# Redirect the user if the $_SESSION has expired in PHP

Tags: php, ajax

On each page I check if the user is connected (i.e.: if the user session is active or not).

```
validateSession();
function validateSession() {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['CurrentLogged_USR_Id'])) {
        header("Location: 'http://example.com');
    }
}
```

It's working.

But if the user is on a page from a long time and the system needs to make an ajax call, the same check is done but do not redirect the user.

Why ?

I've include the `validateSession()` on my php page called by ajax but the redirection is not make.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot redirect in `PHP` that is called through `AJAX`. Rather return a flag that identifies that session has expired and make redirection in `JavaScript`.

Below is sample code snippet.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "urlToAJAX.php",
    success: function(isSessionExpired){
        if(isSessionExpired)
        {
            window.location = "http://example.com";
        }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code.

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
   url:..
   type:..
   success(data){
      if(data == "SESSION_EXPIRED"){
          window.location = "your-login-page";
      }
   }
});
```

In your PHP code, you have check if the session is available. If not echo the string `SESSION_EXPIRED`.